# Javascript issue on resizing Divs

Tags: javascript, css

I kindly ask if someone can look at this c0de and tell me why it doesn't work.
It's fairly simple, I need to calculate the dive size because I want it to resize accordingly
With page width. Keeping Div1 and Div3 at a fixed size and make it dynamically for Div2.

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/yMcXm/89/

Thanks a lot

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cw = $('#container').width();
var d1 = $('#d1').width();
var d3 = $('#d3').width();
$(".d2").width(cw-d1-d3);


$(window).resize(function() {
var cw = $('#container').width();
var d1 = $('#d1').width();
var d3 = $('#d3').width();
$(".d2").width(cw-d1-d3);
});
});
```

Comment: you want div 1 & 3 to have fixed width and div2 to be 100%?

Answer (score 2):

You should change your JS to this (wrong selector (you use `#` (id) instead of `.` (class))).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cw = $('#container').width();
var d1 = $('.d1').width();
var d3 = $('.d3').width();
$(".d2").width(cw-d1-d3);


$(window).resize(function() {
var cw = $('#container').width();
var d1 = $('.d1').width();
var d3 = $('.d3').width();
$(".d2").width(cw-d1-d3);
});
});
```

You should also mind the margins and paddings `$(".d2").width(cw-d1-d3-12);`!

[EDIT]
Why not use a CSS solution: [check your updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/yMcXm/90/)

Comment: LinkinTED's CSS based Fiddle link seems to be the right answer.